# Get third party licences using go get

Tags: go

Let's say we've got a `go.mod` file that defines third party dependencies. Is there a feature or a way in the language to get a list of the third party licenses preferably without third party tools? Unfortunately, I can't share any code because I haven't found any potential solutions yet.

For example we have:

```
module github.com/myGoProject

require (
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.4.2
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.2.2
)
```

How can I get as output:

> MIT
>
> MIT

Comment: This is not a feature of the go toolchain, as there's no enforced standard for storing license information. You might be able to guess (i.e. by checking the root for `LICENSE.txt` or similar), but you'd have to write your own tooling to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had to do this recently and didn't find any "official" way of doing it. I used a tool called `go-license-detector` against my vendored third-party dependencies to automate most of the work.

1. Install https://github.com/src-d/go-license-detector. This tool scans directories for 
   license files and determines what license they (probably) are.
2. Download the source code for all the third-party library dependencies by running `go mod vendor`. This places all the source code for your dependencies into a directory named "vendor".
3. `cd` into your vendor directory and run:

   `` license-detector `cat modules.txt |grep "^#" |cut -d' ' -f2` ``

This will run `license-detector` against each downloaded module and output a list of probable licenses for each module. You'll get output that looks like this:

```
github.com/influxdata/influxdb
    91% MIT
github.com/influxdata/platform
    99% MIT
    84% MIT-feh
github.com/kr/logfmt
    100%    Unlicense
    98% MIT
    93% JSON
    84% MIT-feh
```

Usually the top license is the right one but it's best to double-check each one.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't the full dependency graph the one in `go.sum`? `modules.txt` seems closer to `go.mod` which contains (mostly) direct dependencies?

Comment: The purpose of the vendored dependencies is to have a local copy of _all_ dependencies required to build so the vendor directory (and `modules.txt`) will have all your direct dependencies (from go.mod) plus all transitive dependencies.  As an experiment, I've also tried deleting everything cached in my `~/go` directory and verified that building using the `-mod=vendor` flag did not need to download anything else.

Comment: It is painfully slow. It took 32 secs on my windows 10 pc for detecting one Apache-2.0 license and it did output `100% Apache-2.0` correctly. It claims to do it in 13 secs for 1000 repos on the Readme.